# UWP toolkit Adaptive Grid View - items style

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

Does anybody know how can I change the default border and separation for items in UWP toolkit adaptivegridview?

[UWP toolkit adaptive grid view](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp-community-toolkit/controls/adaptivegridview)

thanks in advance

[image: uwp adaptive grid example]

Comment: I believe that current gap is `5` effective pixels n it's hardcoded in the class. I'd simply change the margin of your data template to adjust it.

Comment: @JustinXL thanks, I added the margin but then when I click/hover the item a border appears around the data template and looks weird, any other ideas?